# Why is my site giving me a relationship field error?

Tags: ee2, relationships, database

I pushed an update to my ee site recently and came across a very strange error where none of my pages work in the site properly and I get a relationship field error on the homepage which was never there before.

This is what I get:

```
Severity: Warning
Message: Wrong parameter count for array_unique()
Filename: relationship_parser/Tree_builder.php
Line Number: 122

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 79
Filename: relationship_parser/Parser.php
Line Number: 52

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/sites/a/arcadiaportal-beta.co.uk/public_html/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 408
```

Has anyone ever come across this issue before with the ee relationship field?

Cheers
Mark

Comment: When you say "pushed and update", do you mean to your templates, or to your EE version? I'd start by inspecting all of your template code which calls relationship fields, and making sure that the syntax is current and correct for the EE version you're using.

Comment: Well after all this I rolled back my version and reverted my db back to the original one. It worked fine from the reverted version I have just rolled back to but now the site still has the error even though it should not have it.

Comment: Has there been a change to the version of PHP on your server?

Comment: Have you checked to see if all the fieldtype files got uploaded when you upgraded?